# discovering pointers and having leak of memory

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-leaks

I have a problem trying to use pointers. I have installed valgrind and after using it to inspect leaks of memory, I see one due to new int(). However, I have exactly the same number of new and delete.I don't understand. Can you see the problem ?
Thank you for helping

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{   
    const int* ptr = new int();
    int* val=new int();
    ptr = val;   
    std::cout << *val << std::endl;
    delete val;
    delete ptr;
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `ptr = val;` you are losing the original pointer and deleting the same pointer twice.

Comment: You have UB on calling `delete` on the same pointer twice, how many `delete` you have is irrelevant

Comment: You have two houses, one at 1492 Elm Street, and one at 1984 Elm Street. You want to have them demolished, and you tell the crew to first demolish the house at 1492 Elm Street, and then you tell them to demolish the house at 1492 Elm Street. How many houses do you have left?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here:

```
ptr = val;
```

Then both *ptr* and *val* will point to the same address, and you are a double free/delete on the same address.

I will try illustrate what's happening, let's assume 32bit addresses:

```
int main()
{   
    const int* ptr = new int();      // ptr allocate 4 bytes @ heap
                                     // for illustration purposes
                                     // ptr is @ address 0x80000010
    int* val=new int();              // val allocate 4 bytes @ heap
                                     // val is @ address 0x80000020
    ptr = val;                       // now ptr is @ address 0x80000020   
    std::cout << *val << std::endl;  // print out the int @ address 0x80000020   
    delete val;                      // free memory @ 0x80000020
    delete ptr;                      // free memory @ 0x80000020 - this will result in a double-free, 
                                     // no good, program will most likely crash
    
    return 0;
}
```

NOTE: address 0x80000010 and 0x80000020 are just for example illustration, running this application for real the allocated addresses on heap will most likely be completely different.

Comment: You correctly mention that the same memory allocation is freed twice, but you don't mention that one of the memory allocations is not freed at all, or why that is the case. In my opinion, a complete answer should also explain this.

Comment: I totally agree.  I am assuming that the purpose of the program is just to show-case a double-free use-case done in C++.